Create an XML table from a SQL table where the SQL column headings are the first row?
I am trying to select values from a SQL table as an XML table with a particular format.
Using the following table...
SELECT x.*
INTO #t
FROM (VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe')) x(Id, FirstName, LastName)

SELECT *
FROM #t

DROP TABLE #t

I would need an XML output that looked something like this...
<Table>
  <Row>
    <Column>Id</Column>
    <Column>FirstName</Column>
    <Column>LastName</Column>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column>1</Column>
    <Column>John</Column>
    <Column>Doe</Column>
  </Row>
</Table>

I was able to get an output matching this using UNION and XML PATH...
SELECT t1.*
INTO #t
FROM (VALUES (1, 'John', 'Doe')) t1(Id, FirstName, LastName);

WITH t2(xmlTable) AS (
        SELECT t3.Id 'Column'
              ,''
              ,t3.FirstName 'Column'
              ,''
              ,t3.LastName 'Column'
        FROM (
            SELECT *
            FROM (VALUES ('Id', 'FirstName', 'LastName')) t4(Id, FirstName, LastName)
            UNION ALL
            SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15), #t.Id)
                  ,CONVERT(varchar(15), #t.FirstName)
                  ,CONVERT(varchar(15), #t.LastName)
            FROM #t) t3
        FOR XML PATH ('Row'), ROOT('Table'))

SELECT t2.xmlTable
FROM t2

DROP TABLE #t

But this seems wildly cumbersome. Is there a more elegant solution for this? Specifically, can I do this without the UNION, perhaps using only XML PATH?

Formatting in SQL is cumbersome, and it ties the data query to the format. If you want something more elegant, retrieve the results and format them in the receiving code. Then you can separte the column query from the data query: select 'Id', 'FirstName', 'LastName' Union select ...

Please try the following solution based on SQL Server's native XQuery.
It is generic regardless how many columns table has.
Column names are not hard-coded anywhere.
Notable points:

First, inner SELECT is composing  behind the scenes a raw XML (please see below).
Second, XQuery .query() method is composing the desired output "visually" by using XQuery FLWOR expressions.
XPath expression /root/r[1]/* is limiting FLWOR just to one iteration
to retrieve column names dynamically by calling XQuery local-name()
function.

SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, FirstName VARCHAR(30), LastName VARCHAR(30));
INSERT INTO @tbl (FirstName, LastName) VALUES
('John', 'Doe'),
('Mary', 'Pollack');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT (
    SELECT * FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')
).query('<Table><Row>{
    for $x in /root/r[1]/*
    return <Column>{local-name($x)}</Column>
}</Row>{
    for $x in /root/r
    return <Row>{
        for $y in $x/*
        return <Column>{data($y)}</Column>}</Row>
}
</Table>');

Raw XML
<root>
  <r>
    <id>1</id>
    <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    <LastName>Doe</LastName>
  </r>
  <r>
    <id>2</id>
    <FirstName>Mary</FirstName>
    <LastName>Pollack</LastName>
  </r>
</root>

Output
<Table>
  <Row>
    <Column>id</Column>
    <Column>FirstName</Column>
    <Column>LastName</Column>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column>1</Column>
    <Column>John</Column>
    <Column>Doe</Column>
  </Row>
  <Row>
    <Column>2</Column>
    <Column>Mary</Column>
    <Column>Pollack</Column>
  </Row>
</Table>


Is it possible to store the input of the XQuery as a variable in SQL and use that in the .query() instead? i.e., DECLARE @x varchar(200) = '...' so that it is SELECT ... FOR XML PATH('r'), TYPE, ROOT('root')).query(@x)

No, it is not possible. You'll get the following error: "The argument 1 of the XML data type method "query" must be a string literal."

No, it's not possible to do this in a single level of query without using UNION ALL. SQL Server expects the node values to be data from the table, not object or column names (which should be defined static normally).
You can use @YitzakKabinsky's excellent answer, but another fully dynamic option is to use FOR JSON and OPENJSON to aggregate and re-query the data.
SELECT
  (
    SELECT j2.[key] AS [Column]
    FROM (SELECT t.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) j1(json)
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.json) j2
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  )
FROM (SELECT TOP (1) * FROM #t) t

UNION ALL

SELECT
  (
    SELECT j2.[value] AS [Column]
    FROM (SELECT t.* FOR JSON PATH, WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER) j1(json)
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.json) j2
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
  )
FROM #t t
FOR XML PATH('Row'), ROOT('Table'), TYPE;

db<>fiddle

I tested both this and @YitzakKabinsky's answers (brilliant, both of you, thanks!). According to the execution plan, Yitzak Kabinsky's solution was 100% of the query cost when tested with Charlieface's answer; however, Charlieface's solution didn't produce quite the XML format I needed (everything was in a single column as opposed to three separate columns). So, I've accepted Yitzak Kabinsky's answer. Regardless, thank you both for the help!

You're right, I've edited to match. I wouldn't rely on "query cost" as it's not that accurate. Measure actual performance on a big table.
